# Cannot boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot)

Tags: boot

When I get to the bootloader it lists both ubuntu and windows 10. Next to windows 10 it says (on/dev/sda1) when i click windows10, the screen blinks one time and goes directly back to the bootloader. Does anyone know what my problem is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a UEFI machine, you should always be able to bypass grub and boot Windows directly with the EFI menu (some key at power-up which allows you to select device or OS to boot).  Boot the install media and post the results of gdisk -l /dev/sda

Comment: Because I'm not 100 percent sure of what you're telling me I did what I thought you were telling me and in terminal I typed gdisk -l/dev/sda and yielded this: GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5 problem opening -l/dev/sda for reading! Error is 2 The specified file does not exist!

Comment: Ok i ran it as sudo and got actual results.

Comment: *found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.*

Comment: It then sound like you had a UEFI system, but forced a BIOS install of Windows which converted gpt drive to MBR. And Windows does not correctly convert gpt to MBR, leaving backup gpt partition (on of gpt's advantages). But then Linux is not sure if UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR system. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I'm having to type all this on my phone because I don't have internet acces thanks to the usb wireless adapter drivers not being compatible with ubuntu. Number 1 (start sector)2048  (end sector) 1126399 (size) 549MiB (code) 0700 (name) Microsoft basic data Number 2 (start sector) 1126400 (end sector) 366458879 (size) 174.2 GiB (code) 0700 (name) microsoft basic data Number 3 (start sector) 366458880 (end sector) 444583935 (size) 37.3 GiB (code) 8300 (name) Linux file system Number 4 (start sector) 444583936 (end sector) 452397055 (size) 3.7 GiB (code) 8200 (name) file swap

Comment: here is the result of sudo parted -l

Comment: Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  577MB  576MB   primary  ntfs            boot
 2      577MB   188GB  187GB   primary  ntfs
 3      188GB   228GB  40.0GB  primary  ext4
 4      228GB   232GB  4000MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)

Comment: it also listed results for my HDD but that has no operating system installed on it so i didnt post those results.

Comment: im not able to copy and paste the full results becuase this website says its too many characters sorry.

Comment: kevin@kevin-desktop:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for kevin: 
Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos